# private float x = 34f, y = 34f; what does f stand for?

Tags: java

I was reading someone's java code and came across this declaration:

```
private float x = 34f, y = 34f;
```

What does the f stand for? I have never seen this type of declaration before. I can easily assume that it stands for "float" since the type is float, but that's just a wild guess.

Any explanation would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you Google for "java what does the f stand for in a number" you'll find dozens of answers.

Comment: I forgot to write "java" when I searched for it in Google, and I searched for it in stackoverflow, don't get me for a lazy guy, sometimes people are tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f;
>   otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end
>   with the letter D or d.

`f` at the end of 34 makes it a `float` literal instead of a `int` literal

Comment: 34 with f or F at the end is interpreted as a floating point literal.

Comment: Please get your types and the casts straight. `34.4` is a `double` literal (`float f = 34.4;` will result in a compiler error). `34.4f` is a `float` literal. If you write `float f = 34;`, it will compile, but `34` is in fact an `int` literal and gets upcasted.

Comment: [Link to quoted section of Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Answer (score 1):

The `f` means it's a `float` literal. Without it, `34` would be an `int` literal that the compiler would have to cast to a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler is x and y double or float value.